# How I click button of the call function in selenium(python)

Tags: javascript, python, selenium

I'd success move page with submit tags using selenium

but There was a problem at the place where the function was called by pressing the button.

How do I press the button to call a function in python Selenium?

It's a function that I want to call.

```
<.input type="button" value="EXCEL" Onclick="OnExcel()">
```

And this is my phython code

```
log_but2 = "//button[@value='EXCEL' and @type = 'button']"

driver.find_element_by_xpath(log_but2).click()
```

AND this is error code

> selenium.common.exceptions.NoSuchElementException: Message: no such
>   element: Unable to locate element:
>   {"method":"xpath","selector":"//button[@value='EXCEL' and @type =
>   'button']"}

I want call onExcel function in page

Comment: You should correct the input element in your question or is this the real code?

Answer (score 0):

Your locator XPath is wrong.
Since your element is not a `<button>` but you are searching for a `<button>` element it is giving you the `NoSuchElementEXception`.

I'm assuming that the element is `<input>` and not `<.input>`.

Then your XPath should be

```
log_but2 = "//input[@value='EXCEL' and @type='button']"
```

Comment: Thx for answer. But I'd change my code that teach you but same problem again....
Message: no such element: Unable to locate element: {"method":"xpath","selector":"//input[@value='EXCEL' and @type='button']"}